# How do you prove a hilbert transform?

Tags: integral-transforms

I am stuck with this question below, I need help;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how. First use the trigonometric identity

> $$ \sin(at+b) = \sin(at)\cos(b) +  \cos(at)\sin(b).$$

to expand the trig. expression you have then we need [Hilbert transform of $\sin(at)$ and $\cos(at)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) (assuming $a>0$) which are given respectively by

> $$ \cos(as)\quad \rm {and} \quad -\sin(as) $$

I think you can advance now.

**Note:**

1) I only considered the case $a>0$. For the case $a<0$ Hilbert transform of $\sin(at)$ and $\cos(at)$ will be given by

> $$  -\cos(as)\quad \rm {and} \quad \sin(as) $$

2) The Hilbert transform is defined as

> $$  H[f(x)]=\frac{1}{\pi} \rm{pv}\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x-y}dx. $$

Comment: i need some guidance on how to continue on, steps on what to do

Comment: @user124627: You have every thing to advance. First you need to expand $\sin(2\pi f_0t+\theta)$ using the trig. identity which I gave you. Note that $a=2\pi f_0$ and $b=\theta$. Then use the hilbert transform of the functions $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ which you have to know. Basically you need to use the linearity property of Hilbert Transform "$H(\alpha f+ \beta g)=\alpha H(f)+ \beta H(g)$ ".

Comment: @user124627: By the way are you taking a course on integral transforms or the problem comes from applications?

Comment: it comes from applications

Comment: @user124627: You already have every thing you need take your time to work the problem out.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Nice answer (+1).

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Thank you very much for the comment. I really appreciate it.